# call React render() function manually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I was going through React life -cycle method so a questions comes in my mind. SO Sharing here : Can we call react's render() function forcefully ?
as we call $apply() in angular JS

Comment: i don't think this question is answered, the answers give an alternate way to achieve the result but never explains why its not possible to call render manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render a component you can use [ReactDOM.render()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render)
If you want to force a component to update you can use [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)

Comment: but can I call this.render() from any lifecycle method or any user defined method ?

Comment: @abhishek Rendering a component and calling the render method it's not the same thing. Updating a component implies call all lifecycle methods in order